# `jupyter notebook` throws `jupyter` is not recognised error in cmd win 10

Tags: windows, python, cmd.exe, jupyter-notebook

***I moved the question from stackoverflow as it is said that this stack is more suitable***

I am using an python 3.8 in an offline regime. Namely, if I need some package to install, I'll go and download that `package.whl` or `package.tar.gz` and install using `pip install package.whl`. Once I wanted to install jupyter notebook and it required  bunch of other packages to be installed. I patiently installed all that were necessary. At the end, I have the following trace:

```
    pip install jupyter-1.0.0.tar.gz
Processing c:\py38\lib\site-packages\jupyter-1.0.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter==1.0.0) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter==1.0.0) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter==1.0.0) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter==1.0.0) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter==1.0.0) (5.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from jupyter==1.0.0) (7.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (2.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=5.0 in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (18.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython_genutils in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter_core>=4.6.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter_client>=5.3.4 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (5.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (5.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus_client in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter==1.0.0) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (7.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt_toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter==1.0.0) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\py38\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter_core>=4.6.0->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (227)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jupyter_client>=5.3.4->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nbformat->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=0.5; os_name == "nt" in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (45.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from prompt_toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->notebook->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.15.7)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.5.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter==1.0.0) (0.5.0)
Installing collected packages: jupyter
  Found existing installation: jupyter 1.0.0
    Uninstalling jupyter-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled jupyter-1.0.0
    Running setup.py install for jupyter ... done
Successfully installed jupyter-1.0.0
```

I thought "**now it'll work**" but I was wrong, `jupyter notebook` command in terminal threw:
`'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Trying to find a solution I googled and came to know that either I should use Anaconda or have jupyter.exe in my ***C:\py38\Scripts*** path (and that exact path should be added into System variables). But I don't have `jupyter.exe` there, but I have already added ***C:\py38\Scripts*** to above-mentioned place.
I am not willing to use Anaconda (that's another story) and for latter part, there are these files in the folder:

[image]

I tried restarting the PC but to no avail.

Could anyone help with that? Thanks

**Edit:** I don't know what `jupyter-notebook` is supposed to do but when I type it in the `cmd` it throws the following:

```
jupyter-notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py38\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('notebook==6.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter-notebook')()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\py38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1720, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "c:\py38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1482, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "c:\py38\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "c:\py38\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "c:\py38\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
  File "c:\py38\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "c:\py38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Try to run `python -m notebook` or `py -m notebook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found one issue for me that is related to Python 3.8 and Jupyter.
I did all the steps above but none of them really worked.

> The function time.clock() has been removed, after having been deprecated since Python 3.3: use time.perf_counter() or time.process_time() instead, depending on your requirements, to have well-defined behavior. (Contributed by Matthias Bussonnier in bpo-36895.)

it from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), I downgraded to python 3.7 and it worked.

Comment: not sure it was the cause, but it worked when I downgraded to 3.7.4. But, it's now linked to Anaconda

Comment: i guess anaconda is another form of an environment manager, I'm pretty sure you can select the interpreter when creating an environment otherwise there is little point to them.

Answer (score 1):

A 100% working solution:
This is due to "Environment Variables"

Follow these steps:

1. Open the folder where you downloaded "python-3.8.2-amd64.exe" setup or any other version of python package
2. Double click on "python-3.8.2-amd64.exe'
3. Click "Modify"
4. You will see "Optional features"
5. Click "next"
6. Select "Add python to environment variables"
7. Click "install"

Then you can run jupyter in any desired folder you desire
E.g open the "cmd" command prompt and type:

```
E:
E:> jupyter notebook
```

It will get started without showing

> Jupyter' is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

The below commands worked for me:
At the command prompt, run

1. `pip install notebook`
2. `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0):

If not using anaconda, and python/jupyter path is in environment variables - at windows (or powershell) command line type...

```
> python -m notebook
```

See...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I found jupyter notebook was not installed where I thought it was, and therefore my environmental variables needed to be updated.  I found the jupyter.exe file `C:\Users\<NAME OF USER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\scripts`. Once I added this to my environment variables I could run the jupyter notebook command. I also added `C:\Users\<NAME OF USER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages` to my EVs incase there were any dependencies.